# how to install nodejs through command on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

I am not able to install nodejs latest version getting errors. I have a fab file which I use to install nodejs. Following is the definition which I use.

```
def install_nodejs():
    cmds = ['sudo apt-get remove --purge nodejs npm',
            'wget http://deb.nodesource.com/setup -O /tmp/setup.sh',
            '/bin/bash -x /tmp/setup.sh']
    for cmd in cmds:
        sudo(cmd)

    packages = ['python-software-properties', 'g++', 'make', 'ruby-compass', 'nodejs']
    cuisine.package_ensure(packages)
```

On cmd:

```
fab install_nodejs -H admin@core.small.team
```

Error:

```
echo '## Your distribution, identified as "wily", is not currently supported, please contact NodeSource at https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/issues if you think this is incorrect or would like your distribution to be considered for support'

Fatal error: sudo() received nonzero return code 1 while executing!

Requested: /bin/bash -x /tmp/setup.sh
Executed: sudo -S -p 'sudo password:'  /bin/bash -l -c "/bin/bash -x /tmp/setup.sh"
```

Comment: If you look at the error, it tells you that the paxkage you are trying to install is not supported anymore for your OS. The easy answer would be to update your OS, the other would be to force your script to bypass this one way or another

Comment: Also, you should look at this askubuntu question, which deal with the same problem: http://askubuntu.com/questions/672994/how-to-install-nodejs-4-on-ubuntu-15-04-64-bit-edition

Comment: i dont think this is the place to ask this question.

Answer (score 0):

To install a specific version of nodeJs (current TLS 10.15.3 for example)

You can use NVM (Node version manager) :

1. curl -sL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh -o install_nvm.sh
2. bash install_nvm.sh
3. nvm install 10.15.3

Then enjoy.
Good luck